# Visual C++ 2012 doesn't seem to respect default capture in lambdas

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, lambda

In MSVC 2012:

```
const std::string tableString;
std::vector<size_t> trPosVec;
// other stuff...
std::for_each(trIterator, endIterator,
    [&, tableString, trPosVec](const boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>& matches){
        trPosVec.push_back(std::distance(tableString.begin(), matches[0].second));
    }
);
```

This code gives the tooltip error:

```
Error: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=size_t, _Alloc=std::allocator<char32_t>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)
    argument types are: (ptrdiff_t)
    object type is: const std::vector<size_t, std::allocator<char32_t>>
```

which I take to mean it's capturing `trPosVec` by value. It works fine when I specify the capture mode explicitly, `[&tableString, &trPosVec]`. If I try to double-specify like `[&, tableString, &trPosVec]`, it gives `Error: explicit capture matches default.` What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your capture specification indicates that you want to capture all local variables by reference, except `tableString` and `trPosVec`, which you want to capture by value.  If these two variables are the only variables you want to capture, and you want to capture them by reference, you should use the capture expression, `[&tableString, &trPosVec]`, or simply capture all local variables by reference, `[&]`.